# Screen transition effect like subway surfers

Tags: unity

I would like to know how can I achieve this kind of screen transition effect ? The effect is screen independent.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Muh7QFisCfE#t=01m57s

[image]

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a simple particle system. Can you describe what you mean by "screen independent"?

Comment: It starts with small from player's position and then grow from that position to full screen (the same effects is seen on all the mobile devices)....Plz check out video link attached to it....

Answer (score 1):

Placing an animation on a UI panel that goes under other UI elements should do the work. Because canvases are automatically stretched to fit whole screen.

Comment: True, but check in video the effect is spawning on player and then getting bigger to match screen

Comment: Sorry didn't understand, what you mean by "spawning on player"?

Comment: means its starting from player's position from small clouds to full screen clouds

Comment: You can cast world position to screen position, then center your anchors to that point.